# Add margin only in first line using xml

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Please look image below i need to place a textview right of a checkbox.
But i want to be continue below checkbox when textview has two lines.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtExtrasCheckBox2"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
    

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Εξτρα"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtExtrasName2"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
   
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post your entire XML layout? This seems to only be a part of it. Also, [ConstraintLayout might help you](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout)